# While uninstalling CUDA toolkit ran into this problem, what to do?

Tags: deep-learning, cuda, nvidia

I was installing CUDA toolkit and cuDNN for deep learning.
I downloaded the cuDNN libs, downloaded the CUDA toolkit and while installing the toolkit I get this,
[image]

And I never downloaded this, it's always been there.

Then I searched a bit about this and some guy said that we have to uninstall.

[image]

This is from my control panel,

[image]

So is it safe to uninstall these programs? And is this how to actually do it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you previously installed higher versions of CUDA - maybe partially -

Try installing [CUDA 11.4](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) instead.

Even if you want to use CUDA 11.2, uninstalling the above two components will not be a problem, as older versions will be installed instead.

Comment: I'm using tensorflow for deep learning, and for python 3.9 cuda toolkit version required is 11.2. so uninstalling will cause no problem right, thanks